# Google Maps API v3 to Open Street Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

Do you know if there is any easy way to replace the google maps api v3 (javascript) with the open streets map api?

Are their code formations similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is. Just go to the openlayers.org example site below, and scroll down to the examples starting with 'G' especially those about 'Google Maps v3 api'.

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/